# Create a homogeneous DE given a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I can't figure this one out.

You are given $y'' + xy = e^x$ and told that $y_p$ solves this DE. How can you find a homogeneous DE so that $y_p$ is a solution to your homogeneous DE?

Comment: If $y_p'''$ exists then you could obtain one by differentiating both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the DE:  y'' + xy = 0 => let  L = (D^2 + x) y where D= d/dx
=> can be written as Ly = 0

Now Consider the original DE: Ly = e^x => (D - 1)Ly = 0;

Thus you have your Homogeneous DE: (D - 1)Ly = 0

Comment: So the resulting DE would be $y''' - y'' + xy' - xy + y = 0$ Correct?